# Invoke a remote MBean in JBOSS AS 7.1.1 using http/https protocol

Tags: jmx, jboss7.x, mbeans

In General, we use the following code to invoke a MBean in JBOSS AS 7.1.1,

```
JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:remoting-jmx://(bind address to invoke):(default bind port is 9999)");
JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, null);
MBeanServerConnection connection = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
ObjectName mbeanObject = new ObjectName(mBeanName);
connection.invoke(mbeanObject, methodToInvoke, params, signature);
```

We have a requirement wherein we need to invoke a remote MBean using http/https protocol. Is there a way to do it in JBOSS AS 7.1.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/protocol.html#exec) first.  But if you really want to implement something custom, develop a servlet or web service and deploy it on the remote server that would act as a proxy to remote MBeans.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I am seeing your response late. When there was no response for 2 -3 days, I left tracking this. We did went for WebService.